# Observe which window sent a Close() event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a short questions and even after a while of searching through the web I have not found the answer.
I have two windows in a WPF application. One window should just be hidden when the user closes it. When the main window is closed the complete application shall close.

I used

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
```

inside the class of the second window and hoped it would just catch its Close() event but unfortunately it catches all Close() events.

How can I separate between the windows to handle the events independently?

Regards
Larimow

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sender` parameter, that's what it's there for:

```
window1.Closing += Window_Closing;
window2.Closing += Window_Closing;

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var w = (Window)sender;

    // Simple ref test to illustrate, but you can use anything else you want instead
    if (w == window1) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        w.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Just forgot about the sender parameter because I usually do not use it...

Comment: hmm, tried that one:'browserWindow.Closing += Window_Closing;  
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += Window_Closing;  

But does not work. How do i capture the main window?

private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)  
        {
            var w = (Window)sender;

            if (w == browserWindow)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                w.Hide();
            }

            else Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }'

Comment: @Larimow: Keeping a reference to a specific window can be done in whatever way is more suitable for your situation; I can't really offer any advice without context. Your example would work if you did `if (w != Application.Current.MainWindow)`, but I don't want to suggest that this is how you *should* do it.